# Change Icon on jQuery Mobile Collapsible Sets

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working with jQuery Mobile for the first time and I'm having trouble accomplishing what seems like a simple change to the icons on a [collapsible set (accordion)](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html).

I want to change the icon for each of the headings on a collapsible set to an up arrow for the expanded state and a down arrow for the collapsed state.

I've created [a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvMNL/8/) that seems to have the same problem with code that I pretty much copied directly from the jQuery mobile site and modified a little.

Any help or pointers on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs page you refered actually uses the latest Work in Progress version of jquery mobile.So this is a feature we can expect in future versions of JQM.In the current stable version,we will not be able to change the icon by means of specifying a data attribute.

Here is an eg: which uses the Work in Progress version of jqm - http://jsfiddle.net/AAYjF/

But it is advisable to use the stable version.So you can use the following code to acheive this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .ui-collapsible .ui-icon{
            background-position: -180px 50%;/*Position of up icon in icon sprite*/
        }

        .ui-collapsible-collapsed .ui-icon{
            background-position: -216px 50%;/*Position of down icon in icon sprite*/
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <div data-role="collapsible-set">

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section B.</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" >
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section B.</p>
    </div>

</div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

The logic is to use the background position of the down and up icons in the icon sprite for the collapsed and expanded icons

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/6x8ew/

Comment: Ahhhhhh! Future versions. That makes sense. I hadn't read in the docs that they (the docs themselves) were for a non-stable version. The CSS adjustment was how I would have gone as well if it was super important to me to make the icons arrows instead of plus/minus. Mostly I was just curious about why what I thought was the standard way wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help..This is the the link to docs for the stable version.http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you can improve upon this solution but here is a basic idea on one way to accomplish this without hacking into the JQM source.

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){

    $('.ui-collapsible .ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-arrow-u');

    $('[data-role=collapsible]')
        .on('expand',function(){ 
            $(this).find('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-arrow-u').addClass('ui-icon-arrow-d');               
        })
        .on('collapse',function(){
            $(this).find('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-arrow-d').addClass('ui-icon-arrow-u');
        });        
});​
```

I am using jqm's collapsible events to switch to the appropriate icon.

See my [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/FN5Ve/3/).

Comment: **1)** Don't forget about chaining: `$('.ui-collapsible').on('expand', ...).on('collapse', ...).find('.ui-icon')...`. **2)** So you don't select all the widgets in the DOM, event the ones on hidden pages, prefix your selector `$(event.target)`, like so: `$(event.target).find('.ui-collapsible')...` (this takes passing in the `event` var). **3)** If you bind to the `pageinit` event then widgets will already have their `.ui-***` classes. Nice answer.

Comment: This answer helped me - I just changed the selector to include h3 (i.e. `$('.ui-collapsible > h3 .ui-icon',this)`), since I didn't want the icons inside the collapsed content to change.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with jQuery Mobile yet, so take it for what it's worth.

I think you need to put the attributes on the `<div data-role="collapsible-set">`, not on each `data-role="collapsible"`.  Obviously this would only work for all the children, and it wouldn't let you target individual children.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It says in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html) that I should be able to place it at the collapsible-set level or at an "individual collapsible basis" but neither of those are working for me...

Comment: Wrong docs. Notice the word test in the url. Its a feature that isn't implemented yet. Look at the current docs or the docs for the version your using.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery mobile version 1.4.0, you can accomplish this by having the following code in your CSS file

For custom right arrow

```
.ui-icon-arrow-r:after {
  background: url("Path to your image file") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
```

}

For custom down arrow

```
.ui-icon-arrow-d:after {
  background: url("Path to your image file") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
```

}